# How can I dock Google Hangouts inside the browser window, instead of floating or docked on the Windows system bar?

Tags: google-hangouts

As of right now, when I run the plugin it is docked at the bottom of my screen on the Windows system bar. I preferred how Talk was docked in gmail. Is there any way to get that behavior back.

NOTE: I do not want to open google plus to do this. I want it either permanently docked in the browser (all tabs) or exclusively in gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel dumb. I found the answer about 5 minutes after posting this. Figured I post.

From the gmail chat interface you can expand the menu and click "try the new hangouts" option and your old gchat interface that you loved will be updated with all the new hangouts love.

source: http://www.droid-life.com/2013/05/17/tip-manually-turn-on-hangouts-in-gmail-with-this-trick/

Answer (score 3):

This is just another answer that worked for me.

In Chrome, go to Settings, then click on Extensions, then uncheck the "Enable" box for Google Hangouts.

This will make the Hangout chat boxes not float on desktop and still work when you go to Gmail. In Gmail the chat boxes will remain inside the browser viewport.

Comment: AFAIK the Hangouts Extension is not installed by default. It's very likely that you installed the Hangouts Extension and disable it sometime ago.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Go to http://hangouts.google.com

## Extended answer

There are several ways to start to have the Google Hangouts app inside a browser window instead of floating over the desktop. Use Hangouts from the:

1. Gmail web UI -> http://mail.google.com
2. Google+ web UI -> http://plus.google.com
3. Inbox by Gmail web UI -> http://inbox.google.com
4. Contacts preview web UI -> https://contacts.google.com/u/0/preview/all
5. Go to http://hangouts.google.com

## References

- [Get started with Hangouts - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2944865?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

just go to this address - http://plus.google.com/hangouts/_

or on chrome, click on the app launcher with `ctrl` pressed...

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about the Hangouts service (instant messaging), not the Hangouts web chat. I know, it's confusing.

Comment: The proposed link starts a new video call, does not dock the Hangouts app  (the one to be used to access several Hangouts features) inside a window.